# How to resolve "Install-Package : The current environment doesn't have a solution open."

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, nuget-package, msbuild-task

I have a solution having 1 project.
Open Package Manager Console, run Install-Package MSBuildTasks 
But it gave me an error below:

```
Install-Package : The current environment doesn't have a solution open.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  MSBuildTasks 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationExcep 
   tion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetNoActiveSolution,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackage 
   Command
```

I don't understand why it comes. Kindly suggest me waiting for reply. Thanks

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I usually get this error because I created or opened a project (.csproj or other) that doesn't have a saved solution (.sln) associated with it.

If you go to File->Save All it should offer to save the solution somewhere. Save it and that makes the error go away for me.