# Nuget: The current environment doesn't have a solution open

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package

I'm trying to install `DeveloperForce.Web.Login`
I recently updated my nuget to the version `2.8.50313.31`

```
PM> Install-Package DeveloperForce.Web.Login
Install-Package : The current environment doesn't have a solution open.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  DeveloperForce.Web.Login
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetNoActiveSolution,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Comment: Well, do you have the solution open?

Comment: I have the solution open, but for some reason, VS does not recognize the application @UfukHacıoğulları

Comment: Try installing the package from the "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution..." dialog.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve "Install-Package : The current environment doesn't have a solution open."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878674/how-to-resolve-install-package-the-current-environment-doesnt-have-a-solutio)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In the package manager console, make sure to select the default project.

If there are no choices, it means that there is no solution file created for your project. When I tested this, I was able to fix the problem by pressing Ctrl + Shift + S (Save all). Visual studio then prompted me to select a directory for my `.sln` file and NuGet then successfully recognized my solution/project.

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler than you can think of!

J**

### just do -> click on Save All under the File menu

** of MVS and then operate on the console manager

Answer (score -3):

Just like Farshid said, it means that there is no solution file created for your project and in order to fix this, press Ctrl + Shift + S. Visual studio will prompt you to select a directory for your .sln file which will in turn make NuGet recognize your solution.

Comment: Do not repeat answers please